# Oracle 12c: use JSON_QUERY in a trigger

Tags: triggers, oracle12c, json-query

I have a CLOB Json in a column of a table with the following structure:

```
{"sources": [1,2,4]}
```

I'm trying to write a trigger that read the array [1,2,4] and performs some checks:

I'm trying using:

```
DECLARE
TYPE source_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
SOURCES source_type;
[...]
json_query(:NEW.COL, '$.sources') BULK COLLECT INTO SOURCES FROM dual;
```

but I got the error:

```
Row 1: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Any ideas?